# how can I make a hashcat mask for phone numbers in my area code?

Tags: networking, kali-linux, amazon-ec2

I am trying to find my own wifi password in a hashcat hccapx file and i cannot figure out how to make a mask to find it. 
I have made a mask file that contains

```
123$d$d$d$d$d$d$d
124$d$d$d$d$d$d$d
```

and i am trying to run it with `

```
hashcat -a 3 -m 2500 '~/Desktop/hash.hccapx' '/usr/share/hashcat/mask/phone_numbers.hcmask`
```

and i it only runs for 10 seconds and obviously doesn't produce any results.

I am clearly missing something.
what is it?

Answer (score 1):

i found the answer and it was obvious.

the mask needs to have ? not &

```
123?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
124?d?d?d?d?d?d?d
```

All it take is looking into what you just typed again.